# add ban reason module error dict object has no attribute append and load and save methods fail to save and load correctly

Tags: python

Can someone help me with adding information to a key in a dict and updating that information accordingly?

also can someone give me a better method of saving and loading than what i am doing currently?

my current method for the dict key:

```
  def add_banreason(roomname, username, reason):
    roomname = roomname.lower()
    username = username.lower()
    if not roomname in banr.banr_database:
      banr.banr_database[roomname] = {username:reason}
    else:
      banr.banr_database[roomname].append({username:reason})
```

i get an error here saying `dict object has no attribute append`

i am lookin for a result such as this with no error:

```
{roomname: {username:reason, username:reason, username:reason}, roomname: {username:reason, username:reason, username:reason}}
```

my current method of saving and loading:

```
  ### load the database
  def load():
    banr_database = {}
    with open("banr.DB","r") as t:
      data = t.read()
    if data != "":
      for l in data.split("\n"):
        a,b = l.split("):(",1)
        c = [w.split(")-(") for w in b.split("(:)")]
        banr_database[a] = c
    banr.banr_database = banr_database

  ### save the database
  def save():
    l = []
    for a,b in banr.banr_database.items():
      c = "(:)".join([")-(".join(w) for w in b])
      l.append(a+"):("+c)
    with open("banr.DB","w") as t:
      t.write("\n".join(sorted(l)))
```

what i would like is for this info to be saved and loaded in the format in the given example below:

```
{roomname: {username:reason, username:reason, username:reason}, roomname: {username:reason, username:reason, username:reason}}
```

however instead i am getting this:

```
anime-gir):(k)-(a)-(m)-(i)-(j)-(o)-(u)-(t)-(o)-(u)-(m)-(a)-(3)-(1)-(0
```

the reason is not there and the username has been split it is also not in dict format

can someone please tell me what i have done wrong and what code would be appropriate here to do what i want instead of what i currently have?

Comment: question edited i hope i did this right it looks like i did and the answer i accepted still fits my question and i have made my question much more clear then it was before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
banr.banr_database[roomname].update({username:reason})
```

dicts do not have an append ... they do have an update that should do what you want

to save just serialize the data ... pickle works for this ... json does it much faster though

```
import json
db_fname = "banr.DB"
def load():
    banr.banr_database = json.load(open(db_fname))

 def save():
     json.dump(banr.banr_database,open(db_fname,"w"))
```

Comment: +1 Joran Beasley on fast response on answering the first half of my problem if someone can answer the second half for me i would be very happy

Comment: +1 Joran Beasley again thanks u helped me do my module correctly question answered in full

Comment: just an aside you would probably be better off using sqlite for this type of thing